# How to design a ChIP-exo experiment with controls?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, chip-seq, chip

Does anyone have any ideas on how to run a control/input sample for a ChIP-exo experiment?  Is it even necessary to run a control (similar to input DNA for ChIP-seq)?  I'm looking for any references or forums that discuss this issue and experimental design?

This video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qLRI9Bqtso) briefly touches on this issue (t=32.45), indicating NOT to use an Input sample due to the Exo digestion.  However, I don't know how the community (or reviewers) feel about this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is a recently published paper addressing the lack of input controls for ChIP-Exo procedures. https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkw741 Hope this helps